# What is the value returned by this function?

Tags: algorithm, max, minim

My teacher gave us a very hard problem on course of algorithms.

Let's consider the below code in which `random(a)` is a primitive which returns a random integer value,uniformly distributed in `[0;a]`,and has complexity `Theta(1)`.

```
  int test(int n)
{
  if(n<=2) return n;
  int i = random(n-2);
  return test(i) + test(n-2-i);
}
```

1. What may return function for n = 9;
2. What is the minimum value for the expression test(2016)?
3. What is the maximum value for the expression test(2016)?

I tried to generalize the expression for an generic step `k` but I get stuck in the probabilistic things and I don't know how to express them.
It's not a homework, it's just something to think about.

Comment: have you analyzed it? and tried plotting each scenarios?

Comment: You have a good teacher. He encourages you to think.

Comment: So you're expecting us to do your homework ? First, we wouldn't be helping you if we answered these questions for you. Second, SO isn't the place to ask for people to do your homework...
You may ask for someone to help you understand a precise point after explaining what you have already done on it, but you can't just ask us to do the task for you.

Comment: no..I just try to express mathematically the algorithm,an then calculate the recurrence.

Comment: @MitchWheat is not about running the code.This is actually a pseudocode.

Comment: @Carele yes I know..But i don't know how to express the uniform distribution in mathematical terms.That was my question.There I get stucked. And no I don't want the homework being solved.

Comment: @LiorKogan yes ...that I'm doing for almost 3 hours

Comment: The set of possible results does not depend on the distribution, only on the set of possuble values returned by random.

Comment: How I would *start* to think about this is to replace the `random` function with one that always returns `0`, and see how the function would operate for the input `9`. Then, replace it with one that always returns `a` and again see how the function operates with input `9`. Finally, replace it with one that always returns the half-way point in the allowed range (rounding up or down, don't really care) and again see how it operates on the input `9`. That should at least allow you to develop an intuition for possible ways the function *can* operate.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I will try this approach

Comment: Posssible route to solutuon: Calculate the set of possible values for test(3), test(4), test(5), test(6) and test(7). Formulate a hypothesis for test(n). Prove it.

Comment: @n.m. I managed to solve first 2 items using your approach.Last-one seems a little more complicated

Comment: One way to think about it is to pretend that random returns a whole list of possible answers from 0 to a. Then modify the rest of the function to deal with lists instead of individual numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to calculate test(i) for i:3..9 to know what it may return for 9 
We have test(n) = test(i) + test(j) with i+j = n-2, i <= n-2 and j <= n-2 
test(3)= test(1) + test(0) = 1 
test(4)= test(2) + test(0) || test(1)+ test(1) = 2
test(5)= test(3) + test(0) || test(2) + test(1) = 1 || 3 (here start the problems)
test(6) = test(4)+ test(0) || test(3)+ test(1) || test(2)+ test(2) = 2 || 4 
test(7) = test(5)+ test(0) || test(4)+ test(1) || test(3)+ test(2) = 1 || 3 
test(8) = test(6)+ test(0) || test(5)+ test(1) || test(4)+ test(2) || test(3)+ test(3)= 2 || 4 
test(9) = test(7)+ test(0) || test(6)+ test(1) || test(5)+ test(2) || test(4)+ test(3)= 1 || 3 || 5 
So test(n) may return even number that are lower than n if n%2 =0, and an even number that are lower than n in the other case (which is cool) 
As for minimum test(2016) if the random always return 0 you will have test(2016)= test(2014)....=test(2) =2 
For max test(2016) it is 1008, if the random always return (n-2)/2
I made the edit test(2016) = 1008 in fact 
test(4n) may return {2,4,...,2n}
test(4n+1) may return {1,3,...,2n+1}
test(4n+2) may return {2,4,...,2n+2}
test(4n+3) may return {1,3,...,2n+1}
I think that this can be verified by induction, it is true for n =1 
test(4n+4) = test(2) + test(4n) since test(4n) may return = 2n we have test(4n+4) may return 2n + test(2) = 2n +2 
since test(4n+4) may return test(4n+2) and also test(4n) => test(4n+4) may return all the value returned by test(4n) => it can return {2,4,... 2n+2} 
It is abvious that test(4n+4) can't return an aneven number it is the sum of tow test(i) and test(j) and since i+j = 4n+4, i and j are both even or both an even and with induction's assumption the result is an even number. 
Last step is to prove that test(4n+4) can't be bigger than 2n +2: 
test(4n+4) = test(i) + test(j) with i+j = 4n +2, again with induction's assumption max(test(i)=< (i/2)+1 and max(test(j)) <= (j/2)+1 
so test(4n+4) <= 2n + 3 and since it is an even number test(4n+4) <= 2n + 2.

Comment: I agree with your answer but I just wanna to mention that in third case the maximum is obtained if the test(2016) is split in t(2014) and t(2)..and so on.I managed to obtain the maximum = 1008

Comment: you can't split it in  t(2014) and t(2) because 2014 +2 = 2016 and the sum should be 2016 -2 =2014